# Problem with memory management

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Here is a sample code, i am trying to import contacts for the iphone to my app.

```
-(IBAction)import_Clicked:(id)sender{

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];   //leaking here
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];


picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];}
```

i ran this on instruments and it shows me 100% leak at line where i alloc abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller. i realsed it after persentmodalviewcontroller. where else could i go wrong.
Any Help , Please.....

Comment: This is taken directly from Apple's [QuickContacts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) project, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is QuickContactsViewController.m > http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a strange SDK bug at large here...  Have a read of the official Apple dev forums [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2756741&tstart=60) for more information and a solution.

Comment: That forum post is not a solution, it is just masking the problem by leaking more memory in a fashion that Leaks does not identify (because the objects are still referenced from the root graph of objects).

Comment: Not only that, but that isn't the official apple dev forums at all.  If it was, I suspect one of the Apple engineers would have noticed how fantastically wrong the "solution" is and would have commented.

Comment: Thanks for the input bbum.  Any input as to what the problem could be here?

Comment: Looks like an honest leak in the frameworks.  Someone should file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, that doesn't looks like a leak to me, heard that Instruments (rarely) report false leaks.

**EDIT**: forget what follows and read bbum comment instead :)

Could you please try removing `[picker release]` and then use `autorelease` instead :

```
BPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then see if instruments still report a leak? If not, keep your original code and ignore that false alert...

That is almost the same but using `NSAutoReleasePool` might change Instruments behavior.

Please also note that explicitly releasing like you did is a more cleaner approach than autoreleasing.

Comment: The Leaks instrument shows where the object being leaked was created, not where it was leaked.  The leak is an over-retain elsewhere (since the retains and releases are balanced in that code).

Comment: @bbum, Thanks for enlighting how instruments works. btw, any interesting links to details of how it detects leaks?

Comment: It scans memory and identifies any object for which there are no longer references to that object from anywhere reachable from global variables or the stack.